70's-80's sci-fi/fantasy movie (TV) with togas and crystals
Movie's title had something to do with an astronomical term. Crystals, caves, and togas were a common theme. A father and son fought with crystal swords. Some existential dread over a long lasting darkness, proof that it had happened before, and a discovery about putting light, energy. or heat into crystals to survive the coming catastrophe.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Did you see this on TV, in a theatre, or from a VHS/disc?  Was it live-action or animated?

Just a guess...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Seeker_(film)? The wikipedia entry doesn't mention the crystal sword, but the book it's based on has it.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Is_Rising_Sequence

Did it feature a rotating sonic weapon?

@CristobolPolychronopolis That would be about 30 years too late for the movie in question?

Ah, never mind. I was thinking of The Shape of Things to Come, but no togas or crystal swords there.

I had an answer with The Son of the Stars but the evidence was too flimsy with the information I could find.

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the check mark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

You're describing the 1988 TV movie adaptation of Issac Asimov's Nightfall.  The story takes place on a world with multiple suns that never knows darkness.  Religions have grown up around the legend of darkness, and a historian figure believes the darkness is real, and will come again soon.
From the original short story:

The Cultists said that every two thousand and fifty years Lagash
(their world) entered a huge cave, so that all the suns disappeared,
and there came total darkness all over the world! And then, they say,
things called Stars appeared, which robbed men of their souls and left
them unreasoning brutes, so that they destroyed the civilization they
themselves had built up.

There's a conflict between father and son, a duel fought with stoopid crystal swords, and everyone runs around in togas.  A cave is used as a darkness simulator.
The movie is not very good, and is a poor reflection of the original short story.  It's available on YouTube:




No, there was a typo in the text. It was made in 1988, and Asimov died in 1992.

Weird fact: this actually had a cinema run. I convinced my friends to see it. We walked out after 15 minutes and I got crap about it for months after.

Re, "A cave is used as a darkness simulator" It's been many decades since I read it, but ISTR, in the original story, somebody builds a big, windowless dome, and they poke tiny holes all over it to simulate what it will be like to stand in the dark with stars overhead. Of course they know what darkness is. What they're worried about is how people will behave when it becomes dark everywhere. They have never invented artificial lighting, because they've never needed it. (If you want light indoors, just open the blinds. It's always light outside.)

Much appreciated!

@SolomonSlow does that also mean they never invented fire?

There was also a novel co-authored with Robert Silverberg that I recall being a very good read.

They had fire for cooking and for industrial purposes.  The short story mentions electricians and long distance freezer cars.  That implies serious metallurgy.
